# Proving in planar graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So I have a connected triangle-free planar graph - let's name it G.
So I have proven that there exists a vertex V $$deg(V)\leq 3$$

I proved that using $$m\leq 3n-6$$ where $$n=|V(G)| , m=E(G)$$
along with the basic lemma about sum of degrees.

How can I use it to prove that:

$$\chi(G)\leq 4$$
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use induction on the number of vertices $|V|$ of $G = (V, E)$. The base case is trivial. Assume that the proposition is true for all such graphs with $|V| = n$. Consider $G = (V, E)$ with $|V| = n + 1$. You proved that there is a $v \in V$ with $\mathrm{deg}(v) \leq 3$. Consider the graph $G - v$ with vertices $V \setminus \{v\}$ and edges $E' = \{e \in E \mid e \text{ is not incident to $v$}\}$ (we remove $v$ and all edges incident to it from $G$). Since $G - v$ satisfies the induction hypothesis it can be properly $4$-colored. But since $\mathrm{deg}(v) \leq 3$ we always can properly color this vertex using the color that is not used to color (at most) three vertices adjacent to $v$.